# How to resample and apply function with custom counting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I'm new to data frames and am struggling to figure out how to accomplish the following:

I have a dataframe already as a time series like so:

```
timestamp             uuid    source                        
2017-06-18 10:43:54   abc      two
2017-06-18 03:38:23   fgh      three
2017-06-18 07:37:02   abc      two
2017-06-18 16:49:51   fgh      one
2017-06-19 21:34:10   abc      two
2017-06-19 16:49:51   knn      three
2017-06-19 22:36:10   mug      one
```

I am trying to 1) resample into daily and 2) find out which unique users have more than one source on a given day and get a count of those users

On the 18th fgh has two unique sources (1), and abc only has one source (0), so this would be a count of 1 for that day.

On the 19th no user has more than one source so the count for that day is 0.

Result

```
timestamp   multi_source_users                  
2017-06-18       1
2017-06-19       0
```

I've tried several combinations of resample and groupby, but I keep getting stuck with total counts.

I start with something naive like...

```
df.resample('D').count()
```

Or

```
df.groupby('uuid').count()
```

But I don't know how to build from there.  I keep getting stuck when I have to start compounding methods.

I also know you can 'apply' a custom function, but wasn't able to make this work either.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?  Plus advice for thinking about problems like this in the future?  Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following using `groupby`, with `pd.Grouper(freq=...)`.

```
(df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='1D'), 'uuid']).nunique() - 1)['source'].groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Output:

```
timestamp
2017-06-18    1
2017-06-19    0
Freq: D, Name: source, dtype: int64
```